# MenuProvider: What is the equivalent of invalidateOptionsMenu?

Tags: android, fragment, android-menu, android-view-invalidate

What is the equivalent of `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` in a fragment when using the new MenuProvider API?

When I get some new information at runtime, I need to refresh the menu in my fragment.

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
            //... Rest of code not shown

            requireActivity.addMenuProvider(myMenuProvider, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        }
    }
 
    // ... Rest of code not shown


    fun onDataChanged() {
        //.. How do I refresh my menu using the `myMenuProvider` or the `MenuHost`?
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`MenuHost`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/MenuHost) API that you are using to call `addMenuProvider` has another method: [`invalidateMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/MenuHost#invalidateMenu()):

> Invalidates the Menu to ensure that what is displayed matches the current internal state of the menu. This should be called whenever the state of the menu is changed, such as items being removed or disabled based on some user event.

So you'd call `requireActivity().invalidateMenu()`.